# Backbone, selectively render parts in template

Tags: templates, input, backbone.js, render

I am listing products as table rows, each row contains input fields for specifying the quantity of products.

I made a Fiddle for it here, http://jsfiddle.net/kroofy/4jTa8/19/

As you can see, after the input in the Qty field have been made, the whole row render again.  And because of that the focus of the input field will be lost, which is not good if you want to input more than just one digit, or tab between input fields.

What would be the most elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i built a plugin for backbone called Backbone.ModelBinding that may be able to help in this situation. my plugin allows you to update portions of a view with data from a model, when the model changes.

i've forked / updated your fiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/FEcyF/6/

i removed the binding to the model change. i've also added `id` attributes to the inputs of the form to facilitate the plugin (the attribute that the plugin uses is configurable, though). and lastly, i've added a `data-bind` attribute to the sell price total td.

you can get the plugin here: http://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding/

hope that helps

FWIW: my plugin is an automated version of what Elf is suggesting. I've written code exactly like he is describing, numerous times, which is where the plugin came from. I just got tired of writing that code by hand :)

Comment: And while the code is a little cluttered, I approve of the sentiment.  That's a nifty plugin, @Derick_Bailey.

Comment: @elf thanks :) and i agree on cluttered code. there's a lot going on in there, and it's still a rather young framework. hoping to continue cleaning it up and improve it over time

Comment: It sure helped, thanks! Although I had to use { all: "class" } when binding, since I have multiple rows, and using a static id for them would be bad.

Comment: awesome! and glad you were able to get {all: "class"} working from reading the docs! :)

Answer (score 4):

I would handle this by setting `model.set({qty: _qty}, {silent: true})` and then updating the non-input fields with `this.$`.

As an alternative to the silent treatment: rather than listening for `change` events, listen for `change:qty` and `change:sellPrice` and have a method that updates just the HTML that needs updating within `this.$`, rather than re-rendering the DOM object and breaking your focus.

Either way, your comment about "selective updating" on the fiddle is certainly the right way to go.

(`this.$` is a backbone hack to jQuery that restricts all selectors to search only within the DOM of the View's element.  The element doesn't even need an ID or class; it just needs to exist and the View maintains a handle to it.  It's incredibly useful.)